# Booting from USB/CD on Lenovo y510p

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I forgot my windows 7 password on a Lenovo y510p laptop. I'm trying to boot from CD, in order to reinstall the OS or boot from USB to reset the password. Both options fail because of EFI security policy -- `EFI XXX has been blocked by the current security policy`.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I solve this problem? I don't see any `security policy` related options in BIOS, to reset them.

Comment: Based on your screenshots, whatever CD your attempting to boot from, your obviously attempting to boot it in EFI mode instead of legacy mode. *All of your other devices are booting in legacy mode.*

Comment: What tool did you use to make the bootable device?